# How do I select the first 84 rows of my x categorical variable (exposed) to compute the mean of my continuous y variable using r?

Tags: r, statistics

I've tried using the mean function, as well as summary. I've also tried tapply and tried to select rows but it computes the overall mean.

Comment: Hi, you should add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): it will be easier to find a solution and summarizing your problem might help you too to find a solution. You can use several datasets included in base R such as ```mtcars``` or ```iris```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  x = factor(c("A", "B", "C")) %>% sample(100, replace = TRUE),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

data
#> # A tibble: 100 x 2
#>    x          y
#>    <fct>  <dbl>
#>  1 B     -0.271
#>  2 C     -0.361
#>  3 C      1.17 
#>  4 A     -0.652
#>  5 A      0.770
#>  6 C     -0.605
#>  7 B      0.976
#>  8 B      0.392
#>  9 B      1.08 
#> 10 A      0.548
#> # ... with 90 more rows

head_means <- 
  head(data, 84) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize_at("y", mean) %>% 
  ungroup()

head_means
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x          y
#>   <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1 A      0.132
#> 2 B      0.385
#> 3 C     -0.110
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Feel free to incorporate this, or a variant of it, into your question.